# Is it okay to operate on a collection member in the Decorator pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, decorator, builder

I was implementing a decorator the other day and later that night I started wondering if something like the example below was a valid representation of the decorator pattern.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public abstract string GetNames();
}

public abstract class BarDecorator : Foo
{
    public abstract String GetNames();
}

public class JustAnOldBar : Foo
{
    public JustAnOldBar() {
        this.Names.Add("An Old Bar");
    }

    public override string GetNames()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this.Names.ToArray());
    }
}

public class SomeDecorator : BarDecorator {
    private Foo foo;

    public SomeDecorator(Foo someFoo) {
        this.foo = someFoo;
    }

    public override string GetNames()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this.Names) + "," + string.Join(",", this.foo.Names);
    }
}
```

Usually, when I implement this pattern, I'm looking at a single member that I'm pulling across like cost or description, but I wonder if it's appropriate to operate on a collection with a decorator or if you should start looking at a builder when it comes to this point.

Comment: Just a decorator to me. Nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorating, in the Decorator pattern, has no dependency of the fields (if any) that are involved in the decoration. It is about *modifying the **behavior*** of decorated classes. As exampled in the [wiki definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#First_Example_.28window.2Fscrolling_scenario.29), it might just as well decorate the drawing behavior of a window, rather than manipulate a field or return value of a method.

In short - as Wiktor Zychla commented - no problem with that.